# How can I determine whether a feature class is a 3D feature class (HasZ)?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, development, .net

I would like to be able to determine whether a feature class passed to a procedure is a 3D feature class (hasZ) or not. 
How can I do this in VB .Net & ArcObjects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the geometrydef of the Shape field

```
Dim field as IField
set field = = class.Fields.get_Field(class.Fields.FindField(class.ShapeFieldName))
hasz = field.GeometryDef.HasZ
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HasZ](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000194000000) on [IDEFeatureClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004tw000000).